# Sort files in the folder

Tags: python, sorting

I need to clean up my archive folder such that only top two files sorted by type of release and the version id are retained.

I broke the file name into a list and tried with an operator.itemgetter but sorting multiple times is a costly operation.

Example:

`1.0.0-release-735586.zip
1.0.0-release-447088.zip
1.0.0-release-436044.zip
1.0.1-patch-480506.zip
1.0.1-patch-968125.zip
1.0.1-patch-532147.zip`

should be

`1.0.0-release-735586.zip
1.0.0-release-447088.zip
1.0.1-patch-968125.zip
1.0.1-patch-532147.zip`

Comment: use groupby and then sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `itertools` [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) i.e

```
from itertools import groupby
li = ['1.0.0-release-735586.zip', '1.0.0-release-447088.zip', '1.0.0-release-436044.zip',
 '1.0.1-patch-480506.zip', '1.0.1-patch-968125.zip', '1.0.1-patch-532147.zip']

new= []
for key, group in groupby(li, lambda x: x[:-10]):
    new.extend(sorted(list(group),reverse=True)[:2])
```

Here we can group the list elements by excluding their last 10 characters ie `'1.0.0-release-735586.zip'[:-10]` will give `'1.0.0-release-'`.

For every group we are taking only first two elements by sorting them in descending order. Which is done by `sorted` and `[:2]`

```
new
['1.0.0-release-735586.zip', 
  '1.0.0-release-447088.zip', 
  '1.0.1-patch-968125.zip', 
  '1.0.1-patch-532147.zip']
```

Comment: Solution is fine but can you explain what exactly happens in the second line ? you are extending the list with the sorted list of groups objects. reverse=True is sorting them in ASC order. but [:2] meaning takes element 0 and 1 ?

Comment: I have edited the answer. Hope that give some insights. ;)